# Unable to install monodevelop

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

```
cyborg@CyBorg:~$ sudo apt-get install monodevelop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 monodevelop : Depends: libmetacity-private0 (>= 1:2.26.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: help me!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f  
sudo apt-get install libmetacity-private0  
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```